# Is it possible to set a crontab to run with different parameters just for the next run?

Tags: linux, cron

I currently have a script running in a crontab every 4 hours. Normally it is running with the following setup:

`python3 -u script.py -s -q --load=ims | tee -a script.log`

Is it possible to say "hey crontab, next time you run use the `--redo` flag on the python script, then continue as normal".

So it would run that entry as `python3 -u script.py -s -q --load=ims --redo | tee -a script.log` and then continue on as normal

Comment: Why was this downvoted with no comments or answers?

Comment: Welcome to the site! People have their own reasons for upvoting / downvoting, but generally upvotes are attracted to questions that show evidence of research. "I want to do this, and here's what I've tried" tends to get voted higher than "Can I do this?"

Looking at your question, I'd have started with trying to keep it from running during the next schedule and using `at` to schedule a one-off run with --redo. But I just searched for "crontab exclude specific time". It doesn't look like it's supported.

Comment: So what now? Maybe remove the line from your crontab, then schedule the one-off run with `at`, and then schedule `at` to run another command that re-adds the entry to your crontab. Or create a file called /tmp/redo. Write a wrapper script to call python. Have it include --redo if /tmp/redo exists. And have it remove /tmp/redo after checking, so it doesn't run with `--redo` the next time. Think about what approach might work for you. If you run into trouble, post a question explaining what you've tried and what problem you're facing. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like this is currently supported in crontab.

Alternatively, you can use the `at` command to run a command at a specific time. For example:

```
at> python3 -u script.py -s -q --load=ims --redo | tee -a script.log 
at> ^D
```

That will run with that parameter at that specific 12:00

---

Another option is to create a Bash file that will modify the crontab entry before the next crontab run and then fix it after the crontab starts the script:

```sh
crontab -l | grep -v 'python3 -u script.py -s -q --load=ims' | crontab -
(crontab -l ; echo "(crontab -l ; echo "* */4 * * * python3 -u script.py -s -q --load=ims --redo | tee -a script.log") | crontab -") | crontab -
sleep 5m
crontab -l | grep -v 'python3 -u script.py -s -q --load=ims --redo' | crontab -
(crontab -l ; echo "(crontab -l ; echo "* */4 * * * python3 -u script.py -s -q --load=ims | tee -a script.log") | crontab -") | crontab -
```

That will find and delete the old entry, add a new one with the flag, then sleep for 5 minutes.

Then it will find the new entry and delete it, then replace it with the old entry